# gmail API watch webhook: how to get the user-id

Tags: push-notification, google-api, gmail-api

We need to use push notifications for many users, using watch Gmail API call.

The watch response we should get on the webhook does not contain any information about the user for which the webhook has been called.

The problem is that according to [Users.history: list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list)
I cannot get messages without user-id.

How am I supposed to get user-id from the watch webhook?
OR
Is it possible to call something similar to "Users.history: list" without the need to have user-id?

Thanks for your support,
Adrien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit from info in link in comment

If you check the [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push) you will see that the response from the server contains a data field.

```
// This is the actual notification data, as base64url-encoded JSON.        
   data: "eyJlbWFpbEFkZHJlc3MiOiAidXNlckBleGFtcGxlLmNvbSIsICJoaXN0b3J5SWQiOiAiMTIzNDU2Nzg5MCJ9",
```

> The HTTP POST body is JSON and the actual Gmail notification payload is in the message.data field. That message.data field is a base64url-encoded string that decodes to a JSON object containing the email address and the new mailbox history ID for the user:

```
{"emailAddress": "user@example.com", "historyId": "9876543210"}
```

Data contains the email address of the user.

Note I don't have the power to test this I am just reading the documentation.  I don't have a server set up to retrieve these notifications.

Comment: the webhook is called by Gmail servers, not by a logged user, see: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push

Comment: Its still a user's Gmail account you are reading from and the quote is directly from the documentation if the documentation says its valid I would suspect it works.  Have you tried it?   If it doesn't in fact work we should probably submit a bug in the documentation.

Comment: from the link you just posted:  https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/watch

Comment: I do not watch the mails of the logged user. I watch mails of other accounts. I will give "me" a try, but it is not clear it should work.

Comment: check update think I misunderstood your question the first time around.  I think I did have this working once ages ago I am trying to remember how I did it by reading the documentation.

Comment: ok, many thanks! I do not noticed data field. I use something like : `WatchResponse watchResponse = (response as HttpResponse).parseAs(WatchResponse.class)` and no data field is present here... Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

user-id is your email, which is used to subscribe push notification